# PHP inheriting or compositing from multiple storage interfaces/objects

Tags: php, interface, storage, multiple-inheritance

I have a situation where I need to abstract with storage functions, and to have multiple database adapters.

However I'm relying on external vendors who also have multiple database adapters for their libraries.

I'd like to create a single adapter be it MySQL that inherits the functions of the corresponding MySQL adapters from the external vendors. I can dependency inject this adapter into my own libraries and the external libraries that depend upon adapters to function.

Of course PHP doesn't have multiple inheritance, so I did some research and came up on composition.

Would compositing multiple database adapters into a single database adapter be a good practice? Furthermore would this composed object work, if it implemented an interface that extends from the corresponding interfaces of the external vendors?

For example imagine having:

```
External1\StorageInterface
External1\MySQLAdapter
External2\StorageInterface
External2\MySQLAdapter
Internal\StorageInterface
Internal\MySQLAdapter

Now: Internal\StorageInterface extends External1\StorageInterface, External2\StorageInterface
Then: Internal\MySQLAdapter implements Internal\StorageInterface
Then: Internal\MySQLAdapter compositions External1\MySQLAdapter and External2\MySQLAdapter
```

On a side note, how should the compositing take place? Via __call or reimplementing the function names, and simply calling the child objects? Which one satisfies the interface constraints?

One more question would be, how does one deal if in the case that different adapters have the same function name creating conflict? Would the adapter pattern work?

Comment: PDO provides a good solid database abstraction, are those not working for you?

Comment: This is got nothing to do with PDO. This about libraries. These adapters may or may not use PDO. But different databases may require different implementations of similar functions, such as MongoDB adapter or a MySQL adapter... etc.

Comment: You know, I dreamt of a circular thing, that could be placed under things, so that we could push them to somewhere else. Then I realized the wheel had been invented already. ZendFW has a DB abstraction layer that does this, but you could opt to use Doctrine, too. Multiple inheritance is generally a bad idea BTW. Even in C++ it's hardly ever used AFAIK

Comment: This is not an "app". I cannot use ZendFW. This is an independent library, independent from frameworks. I've identified that multiple inheritance is not what I'm looking for. Libraries have their own database functions, which is not simple CRUD. But actually related to the functioning of the library. For example see: https://github.com/leighmacdonald/php_rbac/tree/master/src/RBAC/DataStore

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Did I say you should use ZendFW entirely? Just pick and choose those bits that you need... There's no reason why you can't do that

Comment: While I could do that, that doesn't solve my problem. It's not about picking a database abstraction library. It's about integrating third party libraries that have database adapters already prewritten, that is using PDO, which is what I'm using as well.